# Determining ARIMA Model Parameters for Daily Time Series Forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am currently working on time series forecasting at the daily level using the ARIMA model.

As part of this process, I need to determine the appropriate values for the parameters p,d and q.

I have couple of questions regarding this:

1.Given that we are working with daily forecasting,I suspect that the values of p,d and q may be larger. Could you please advise me on the recommended range for these values?

2. In terms of identifying the values of p,d and q, I am unsure whether to rely on ACF or PACF graphs or to use Auto ARIMA approach. Which method would you recommend as the better option?

Answer (score 0):

From examples I have seen these values were always rather low <=3.

I would start with d alone, try 1..2 to check if that is enough for a consistent ACF, i.e. not linearly decreasing.

---

As rule of thumb (which actually only hold if either p or q=0):

p values do you determine from the last significant lag in the PACF
q values from the last significant lag in the ACF.

Alternative the other way round:
p is good if the ACF is exponentially decreasing.
q is good if the PACF is exponentially decreasing.

Source: [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/non-seasonal-arima.html)
Another potential helpful source: [https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411arim3.htm)

---

Auto-ARIMA is normally useful and easier but could lead to slight overfitting.

If you have a good fit try once again with one less p and q value as the MA and AR could cancel each other out. (Rule 10, second link from above)

---

If there are seasonal patterns like every 24h use SARIMA.

Comment: Thanks @Daraan for the response. I just wanted clarification from the below sentence because I had difficulty understanding this: p values do you determine from the last significant lag in the PACF
q values from the last significant lag in the ACF

Comment: @GauthamA I also added two links, the first states what I have written here. So yes p from PACF and q from ACF.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links. I will check them out